# Getting wrong answer when trying to get k subsets from Array in ActionScript

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, flash, recursion, actionscript

I'm working on a Texas Holdem game and i need to generate all possible k subsets from an Array of cards (represented as numbers in this example). This is how it looks so far:

```
public function getKSubsetsFromArray(arr:Array, k:int):Array {
        var data:Array = new Array();
        var result:Array = new Array();
        combinations(arr, data, 0, arr.length - 1, 0, k, result, 0);
        return result;
    }

    public function combinations(arr:Array, data:Array, start:int, end:int, index:int, r:int, resultArray:Array, resultIndex:int):int {
        if (index == r) {
            trace(resultIndex, data);
            resultArray[resultIndex] = data;
            return ++resultIndex;
        }

        for (var i:int = start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++) {
            data[index] = arr[i];
            resultIndex = combinations(arr, data, i + 1, end, index + 1, r, resultArray, resultIndex);
        }

        return resultIndex;


    }
```

I am new to Actionscript, my idea is to have a function that takes an array of number and a parameter k, and returns an Array of arrays each of size k. However once i test the functions I get an array containing only the last combination nCk times. For example:

```
var testArray:Array = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
trace(getKSubsetsFromArray(testArray, 3));
```

Returns:

```
0 1,2,3
1 1,2,4
2 1,2,5
3 1,3,4
4 1,3,5
5 1,4,5
6 2,3,4
7 2,3,5
8 2,4,5
9 3,4,5
```

The function output is

```
3,4,5,3,4,5,3,4,5,3,4,5,3,4,5,3,4,5,3,4,5,3,4,5,3,4,5,3,4,5
```

Of course it should print an array containing all the combinations listed before but it only prints the last one the right amount of times.

Thank your for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is that when you are making array of arrays you are actually using the reference of the same  array (data) so when the last combination is executed the contains of data array become `3,4,5` and each of index of `resultArray` points to data array so it prints out same values.

**Solution :-**

```
if (index == r) {
            trace(resultIndex, data);
            var result = new Array();
            copy(result,data)
            resultArray[resultIndex] = result;
            return ++resultIndex;
}
```

**Note :-**

The above is pseudo code as i am not familiar with actionscript but you can implement copy function that copies values of data into result in actionscript syntax.